# Multidimensional array only returns first indexes

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I know there are lot's of posts with the same title, however, my problem is partially fixed.

Printing the Array:

```
 $data['posts'] = $this->model_mutamba->getPosts($email);
 print_r('<pre>');
 print_r( $data['posts']);
 print_r('<pre>');
```

The Array:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [post_id] => 5
                [aluno_id] => 3
                [post_text] => Hello my name is Joana!
                [post_image] => 
                [post_video] => 
                [post_comments] => 
                [post_likes] => 0
                [post_flags] => 0
                [post_date] => 2014-12-11 03:03:33
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [post_id] => 3
                [aluno_id] => 1
                [post_text] => Mestre zeca na area!
                [post_image] => 
                [post_video] => 
                [post_comments] => 0
                [post_likes] => 0
                [post_flags] => 0
                [post_date] => 2014-12-10 19:37:16
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [post_id] => 4
                [aluno_id] => 1
                [post_text] => ulalalala
                [post_image] => 
                [post_video] => 
                [post_comments] => 0
                [post_likes] => 0
                [post_flags] => 0
                [post_date] => 2014-12-10 21:00:29
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [post_id] => 1
                [aluno_id] => 10
                [post_text] => olaaa a todossss
                [post_image] => 
                [post_video] => 
                [post_comments] => 0
                [post_likes] => 0
                [post_flags] => 0
                [post_date] => 2014-12-10 05:18:11
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [post_id] => 2
                [aluno_id] => 10
                [post_text] => mais umas vez estamos aqui e brindar.
                [post_image] => 
                [post_video] => 
                [post_comments] => 0
                [post_likes] => 0
                [post_flags] => 0
                [post_date] => 2014-12-10 15:17:26
            )

    )

)
```

My project in in CodeIgniter, I tried to loop it like:

```
if ("" != $posts) {
    foreach ($posts as $object) { 
        $p = $object[0];
        echo "<br>" . $p->post_text;
    }
}
```

It shows the text from the posts but not all of them. It only shows the items in the at the [0] index. I also tried something like:

```
$i = -1;
foreach ($posts as $object) { 
    $i++;                             
    $p = $object[$i];
    echo "<br>" . $p->post_text;
}
```

But getting "Undefined offset 2".

I know it must be something simple i'm missing. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to start with 0 and add after the echo.

Comment: I think this only works if $posts has the same length as $object does. Try using a for loop within the foreach loop.

Comment: That's a bizarre thing to do in a foreach loop (second example, the point of a foreach is to iterate through each element of an array, optionally tracking the key. If you want to get each post_text attribute from each $object, just do `echo "<br>" . $object->post_text;` - if you need `$i`, add it as `foreach ($posts as $i => $object) {`. To be honest, it looks like you'll need to use another foreach loop inside your foreach loop to handle the fact that you've got an array within an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot m8 :). I used another loop inside,  foreach($object as $i=>$p1 ). It works ;like magic. I F**** Love StackOverflow :p

Answer (score 2):

You have an array, where each element contains an array of objects.

```
$data['posts'] = $this->model_mutamba->getPosts($email);
// just being really explicit to make sure $data['posts'] is a non empty array
if (is_array($data['posts']) && count($data['posts']) > 0) {
    foreach ($data['posts'] as $array_of_objects) { 
        foreach ($array_of_objects as $object) {
            echo "<br>" . $object->post_text;
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution can be seen working here: http://ideone.com/g1Yqqi for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

I used another loop as suggested by @scrowler.

```
$i= 0;
foreach($posts as $object){ 
    $i++; 
    foreach($object as $i=>$p ){
        echo "<br>". $p->post_text;
    }

}
```

Works like a charm. Thanks to you all for the awesomeness ;)